# Get the return code of a C program in my shell program

Tags: c, bash, shell

Suppose I have a C program named `Foo.c` which is printing few things and returning a value named `rc` which I am executing in my shell program as follows :

`foobar=$(Foo | tail -1)`

Now, the variable foobar has the last printed value of the program `Foo`. But without disturbing this, I want to get the return code `rc` of the program in my shell program.

Comment: Use `$?` variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if $? in this case works since he is using a pipe. So the last command executed is tail -1.

Comment: I did a simple test and it doesn't work. The last returned value is the tail return code

Comment: Its not working. The $? variable shows value 0 even if I hard code the `rc` value as 
`rc=100;
return rc;`

Comment: See the *man bash*: **The  return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command**

Comment: You didn't ask this, but you probably need to know anyway: The parent process (the shell, in this case) only gets to see the low 8 bits of the value you return from `main` or pass to `exit`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use "set -o pipefail" option.

```
[root@myserver Test]# set -o pipefail
[root@myserver Test]# ./a.out | tail -l
[root@myserver Test]# echo $?
100
```

Here my program a.out returns 100.

Or another options is to use pipestatus environment variable. You can read about it here.
http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/03/pipestatus-internal-variable.html

Comment: Interesting option. Just as a note. This will only work if all the other programs in the pipe return 0. From the doc link:  So long as none of the programs following the test program report a non-zero exit code, the pipeline will report its exit code to be that of the test program.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `bash` shell, you can use `PIPESTATUS` array variable to get the status of the `pipe` process.

```
$ tail sat | wc -l
tail: cannot open ‘sat’ for reading: No such file or directory
0
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
1 0
$
```

From `man bash`:

> **PIPESTATUS**
>
> An array variable containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

Answer (score 6):

This assigns the last line of the output of `Foo` to `foobar` and Foo's exit code is assigned to `code`:

```
{ read -r foobar; read code; } < <( (Foo; echo $? ) | tail -2)
```

The `<(...)` construct is called *process substitution*.  In the code above, the `read` commands receive their stdin from the process substitution.  Because of the `tail -2`, the process substitution produces a total of two lines.  The first line is the last line produced by `Foo` and it is assigned to `foobar`.  The second is assigned to `code`.

The space between the first and second `<` is essential.

#### Example

After creating a function Foo, the above can be tested:

```
$ Foo() { echo "Testing"; false; }
$ { read -r foobar; read code; } < <( (echo "Testing"; false; echo $? ) | tail -2)
$ echo "foobar=$foobar code=$code"
foobar=Testing code=1
```

And:

```
$ Foo() { echo "2nd Test"; true; }
$ { read -r foobar; read code; } < <( (Foo; echo $? ) | tail -2)
$ echo "foobar=$foobar code=$code"
foobar=2nd Test code=0
```

Comment: Hey John.. thanks for your answer but Foo is a C function.

Comment: But this fails if `Foo` doesn't output anything, or its last line of output doesn't end with a newline character.

Comment: @kirtan It makes no difference if Foo is a C function or not.  The script works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you have to use a temporal file to store the output of the Foo program, get the return code and then perform the tail -1. Just like the following:

```
Foo > /tmp/temp_file
ret=$?
foobar=$(tail -1 /tmp/temp_file)
```

Comment: This is the only way to do it in *portable* shell.

Comment: ... However, your demo should use [`mktemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html) and delete the scratch file afterward.

Answer (score -1):

`$?` gives the return value of the last executed command.

Comment: The answer from @sat explains why `$?` won't apply to this question.